# Tkinter window not closing after closed file dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to close the File Open dialog after selecting a file.  Currently with my code, I can select a file but the File Open dialog remains open until I click the 'X'.  How can I close this window after I have selected a file.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename   

fname = "unassigned"

def openFile():
    global fname
    fname = askopenfilename()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    b = Button(text='File Open', command = openFile).pack(fill=X)
    mainloop()

    print (fname)
```

Comment: The dialog should automatically close after you click 'Open'... is it not?

Comment: It is not closing.  After I click 'Open' and select a file it remains open.

Comment: @SSS It works on Windows 8 though it doesn't print out the filename

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *file dialog* is closing just fine.  I think what you are trying to say is that the Tkinter window you created to hold the button is not closing after you select a file from the dialog.  To have it do this, you will need to restructure your program a bit.

First, you need to explicitly create a `Tk` window to hold the button:

```
root = Tk()
```

You should then list this window as the button's parent:

```
Button(root, text='File Open', command = openFile).pack(fill=X)
#      ^^^^
```

Finally, you should call the `destroy` method of the `root` window at the end of `openFile`:

```
root.destroy()
```

This will cause the window to close and the Tkinter mainloop to exit.

In all, your script will look like this:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename   

fname = "unassigned"

def openFile():
    global fname
    fname = askopenfilename()
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    Button(root, text='File Open', command = openFile).pack(fill=X)
    mainloop()

    print (fname)
```

Comment: Yes thank you.  That is what I was referring too.  Works exactly how I wanted.